# Why are dimension tables denormalized in an InfoCube?

Tags: normalization, denormalization, sap-bw

I'm in the process of learning SAP BW at work. The SAP class material states that in InfoCubes, dimensions are denormalized. I understand the benefit of normalized tables, but don't understand why dimensions would be denormalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a data warehouse, you're trying to get a faster response time.

The data is loaded one time, and read many times.  Therefore, normalization of data is not an advantage in a data warehouse.

Denormalization is a bit of a misnomer.  In a star schema, the data is not normalized.  I do understand that some people are referring to the data loading process as denormalization.  But, in general, designing a star schema is not a denormalization

By not normalizing the dimension data, you're improving the response time by increasing the load time and storage space for the data warehouse.